# How to send encrypted form data after preventdefault()?

Tags: javascript, go, encryption, form-data

I am using this code to prevent from sending un-encrypted form-data.

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var formString = $( this ).serialize(); // All data in one String.
  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(formString, "Secret Passphrase");
  
  //how to pass the encrypted form ???
  //$('form').unbind('submit').submit();
});
```

But now I don~t know how to pass encrypted form to my backend. Can anyone help me out pls ? any help is appreciated

thnks in advance